# Umbraco content port

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have a site that has been built in umbraco, and discovered that all of its contents are in a file called umbraco.config.

I need to rebuild the site in PHP, so I need to port this data to a different database structure.

Essentially, I need to parse this as a PHP array or something of the like so that I can run scripts on it.

It has a  header, but any attempts to parse it as an array or using an online xml to json converter always comes out with errors.

I was wondering if anybody with experience in umbraco might be able to suggest a fix / alternate solution.

Comment: Umbraco is a CMS which is written in .Net, would you want to port to another CMS in PHP?

Comment: Do you only need the data, or do you need to copy the website's templates too?

Comment: I just need the content itself! Its a site that I have to rebuild because we are a PHP dev house who inherited an umbraco site, however the people who we inherited the code off, wont give us the actualy source code, only the precompiled code

Answer (score 3):

I think you are mistaken, all the data in Umbraco are stored in the database. The umbraco.config file stores only published content for faster access, see the [umbraco community website page](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/files-and-folders/umbracoconfig-format).

So assuming that you want to copy the whole content, you need to find a way to read the data from the [Umbraco database](http://blog.hendyracher.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Umbraco-Schema-with-Constraints-v2.gif) and transform them into the new format.

Alternatively, if you have significant knowledge of how to develop against Umbraco, you can use the [Umbraco Management API](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/) and expose the data in a meaningful way, making the import to your new system easier.

Another option would be paid Umbraco plugin called [Courier](http://umbraco.com/products/more-add-ons/courier-2.aspx). You can export Umbraco content in some other format like csv or xml, a demo video is available [here](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/umbraco-pro/contour/export-your-data-with-one-click.aspx)

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense, but the only reason I ended up at the config file is because I couldn't find anything in any tables that even looked like content, any clues?

Comment: Have a look at [this diagram](http://blog.hendyracher.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Umbraco-Schema-with-Constraints-v2.gif), even though it might be a little outdated. 

Also, what's your proficiency with .NET? You could expose the data through a webservice using the Umbraco Management API instead of directly migrating the database

Comment: +1 makes good sense to use webservices and detailed umbraco knowledge to ease the migration - I've got an idea that it might be simpler if the OP simply starts again from scratch if their .Net knowledge is rudimentary.

Comment: You can find XML format of each Umbraco node in table named cmsContentXml. In order to find which one is for which Node you need to join this table with umbracoNode table.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to move an Umbraco .net site to php you need to consider more than the data.

I'd suggest that you need to build the structure you want to import the data into using the document types; then consider how you'll render the pages using the templates and then you are in a position to import the data.

In an Umbraco site when you add a page you choose a document type and a name for the page; once it is created you can choose a template for how the page will be rendered.  I'd suggest that you replicate this into whichever php CMS you choose to migrate to (even if you create your own CMS).  Once you can port the document types into your new structure the data will have somewhere logical to be stored.

In the umbraco back-office in the 'settings' section you will see the document types.  Every page that can be rendered has a single document type which can have many templates (the templates determine how a page is rendered).  The document type controls what text, images etc can be content managed for this type of page, how pages of this type can sit in the site structure and so on.

Pages are rendered depending on the template If the implementation is Umbraco 4 then the page templates are stored in the /masterpages folder; if you are in Umbraco 5, 6 or 7 you will need to look in /Views - this will give you an idea of how to render the data to the browser for each page.

Now you know how to structure your content & render the content you can import the content.  The umbraco.config file will now make some sense as you will see the doctypes and templates and how they interact with the content.  Ideally you should know a lot more about how Umbraco works before even attempting this (a couple of years should be enough) - but we all know that that kind of luxury is rare!